# 64 bit python breaks Matplotlib plot menu

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib, 64-bit

Due to memory limitations of 32 bit application, I had to update our python installation to the 64 bit version. I've made everything functional again (modules and 3rd party libs), but have noticed a potential bug in a matplotlib figure. See the image below. This is a typical matplotlib in perfect functionality. Please note the menu in the bottom left corner.

For some reason, running the 64 bit version, this menu simply dissapears. This is very unfortunate as we really do use the menu on this app.

Any idea how to force the menu to display?

Please note that although the figure below indicates linux, we are in fact using this on Windows. The image is simply to show exactly what menu I'm talking about.

EDIT - 
I have made a simple hello world that replicates the error.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure('Hello World',figsize(10,15))
plt.show()
```

I believe this error happens when the figsize extrapolates the screen size, matplotlib simply does not render the toolbar. Even when I resize the figure to until it fits the screen, the toolbar is still missing.

[image: matplotlib]

Comment: Why do you think this caused by the `64 bitness`? This seems very unlikely.

Comment: Yes, the rest of the world uses matplotlib on 64bit architecture for a long time and has no problems with the menu.  How can we recreate your issue?

Comment: What do you get from `import matplotlib; print(matplotlib.rcParams['toolbar'])` ?

Comment: @cel: Only difference between the two versions.

Comment: @wim: Your lines return 'toolbar2' in command line python.